# c# Should i put null check for useragent?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-agent

I am extracting user agent as:

```
string userAgent = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent;
```

Is there any possibility that UserAgent would be null? Is it only possible for bot or for any legitimate user/device/client/browser too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The User-Agent header is optional in RFC 2616. It [SHOULD](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) be used by clients, but it is not REQUIRED to be used.  Also see [RFC7231](http://svn.tools.ietf.org/svn/wg/httpbis/specs/rfc7231.html#rfc.section.5.5.3):

> 5.5.3 User-Agent
>
> The "User-Agent" header field contains information about the user agent originating the request, which is often used by servers to help identify the scope of reported interoperability problems, to work around or tailor responses to avoid particular user agent limitations, and for analytics regarding browser or operating system use. A user agent SHOULD send a User-Agent field in each request unless specifically configured not to do so.

I *think* RFC7231 obsoletes 2616, but I have cited both for completeness.

So yes, you should check for a null or empty user agent.